# sql server : There is already an object named 'abc 'in the database

Tags: sql-server

I almost pulled all of my hair for this issue.

I tried to create a synonym on my SQL Server and I got this error

> There is already an object named abc in the database

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[abc] FOR [dbo].[tablexyz]
```

it's a simple creation.  I've checked everywhere and found nowhere this object abc, `object_id('abc')` returns `NULL`, nothing returns from `sys.objects`, `sys.all_objects`.  I even checked indexes but with no luck. Can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Presumably if you called `CREATE SYNONYM` with a schema specified the error would have been "There is already an object named 'dbo.abc' in the database". So try `object_id('dbo.abc')`. Also check sys.synonyms.

Comment: Hi Strickt01, thanks for the suggestion.  I've checked in sys.synonyms and object_id('dbo.abc'), and I found nothing.  do you have any other ideas?

Comment: guess what,  I finally found out that the database is corrupted.  oh my, waste two days on this thing.

Comment: You have my sympathies. Sounds infuriating!